# Show the x value on the x-axis for each point in a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a ggplot with some points and I would like to show all the x values on the x-axis.

```
day = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
value =c(4.63, 3.58, 3.52, 4.42, 4.09, 3.51, 3.95, 4.51, 3.45 ,1.76)
data <- tibble(day, value)

data %>% ggplot(aes(day,value)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

So instead of showing: 2.5,5.0,7.5,10 I would like to display all values between 1 and 10.

How can I do this?

Comment: Probably with `+ scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:10)` or `+ scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::breaks_width(1))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your x axis `as.factor`

```
day = as.factor(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
value =c(4.63, 3.58, 3.52, 4.42, 4.09, 3.51, 3.95, 4.51, 3.45 ,1.76)
data <- tibble(day, value)

data %>% ggplot(aes(day,value)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is not the best approach because it relies on the fact that `days` is ordered the way `as.factors` orders the levels. Try with `day = as.factor(c(2,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))`.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment. And I agree with you. Anyway you can change the order of items by setting limits in scale_x_discrete(). Add `+ scale_x_discrete(limits = day)` to ggplot. This scenario is helpful in variables that are categorical(=factor). Here I believe we have with `day` a scalar variable!  In some scenario this might not be that clear. Therefore having this in mind could be helpful. For a more in-depth look at <https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/469840/why-or-why-not-factor-categorical-variables-in-regression-modeling>